# How to get selected ids from checkbox into select option?

Tags: php

I have a table which displays users and I added select all checbox into it to delete sellected users or send email.

This is how I collect ids : `<input type="checkbox" class="check" name="del[]" value="<?php echo $author['user_id']; ?>">`

And I added a select option under the table with two options, Delete or send email.

When I choose delete it should delete selected ids, if I select send email then it should return email function.

The problem is I couln't get selected ids into select option.

Note: php and html codes are in same page

**Question : How to get selected ids from checkbox into select option ?**

Here my codes of table :

```
<form action="" method="post">
   <thead>
       <tr class="table-success">
       <th scope="col">
           <div class="checkbox">
             <label>
               <input type="checkbox" class="check" id="checkAll">
             </label>
           </div>
        </th>
           <th scope="col">Username</th>
           <th scope="col">Name</th>
           <th scope="col">Email</th>
           <th scope="col">Role</th>
           <th scope="col">status</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       <?php foreach($authors as $author): ?>
       <tr>
          <th scope="row">
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" class="check" name="del[]" value="<?php echo $author['user_id']; ?>">
                </label>
              </div>
           </th>
           <td><?php echo $author['username']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $author['user_fname']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $author['user_email']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $author['user_role']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $status; ?></td>
       </tr>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
   </tbody>
   <tfoot>
       <tr class="table-success">
          <th scope="col">
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" class="check" id="checkAll">
                </label>
              </div>
           </th>
           <th scope="col">Username</th>
           <th scope="col">Name</th>
           <th scope="col">Email</th>
           <th scope="col">Role</th>
           <th scope="col">status</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
       <th colspan="6">
        <select name="users_operation">
           <option value="" disabled selected>Choose option</option>
           <option value="delete" id="delete">username</option>
           <option value="sendMail" id="sendMail">Send Email</option>
         </select>

          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
         </th>
       </tr>
   </tfoot>
</form>
```

PHP codes :

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 
 if(!empty($_POST['del'])) {
        $selectedIds = $_POST['del'];
 }
 if(!empty($_POST['users_operation'])) {
    if(!empty($_POST['delete'])) {
       //Do query
        print_r($_POST['del']);
        
    } elseif(!empty($_POST['sendMail'])) {
       // Send email
        print_r($_POST['del']);
        
    } else {
        echo 'Please select the value.';
    }
 }
}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: "The problem is I couln't get selected ids into select option." Do you mean you want to create a `<select>` with the IDs, but can't figure out how to populate the `<option>`s? Or do you mean you can't get the IDs from the user input to use *for* the selected action (delete, send mail)?

Comment: @outis Actualy I didnt know how to explain it, I want to post ids to php and do query on selected option delete or send email.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood how select boxes work since you seem to try and fetch the options based on `id` and also have given them the same value. When the form is submitted, it will be with the `name`-attribute. So `$_POST['users_operation']` will contain the `value` of the selected option. `id`'s aren't submitted so there are no `$_POST['delete']` or `$_POST['sendMail']`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson see my updated question, I get ids in **first if(!empty($_POST['del'])) {** but dont get in print_r.

Comment: Like I said, there won't be any `$_POST['delete']` or `$_POST['sendMail']` so it will always go to the `else`-block. You need to check if `$_POST['users_operation'] == 'delete'` and `$_POST['users_operation'] == 'sendMail'`

Comment: Ah damn me, sorry. Thanks a lot.